# Use JavaScript Objects with jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I use [jquery ui autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) on a form to autocomplete city and postal code from a text file.

The text file is formatted like this :

```
FR;24108;Bergerac
FR;24109;Bergerac
FR;24110;Léguillac-de-l'Auche
FR;24110;Saint-Léon-sur-l'Isle
FR;24110;Manzac-sur-Vern
```

The autocomplete works on the corresponding field but I would like when user choose a postal code to fill automatically the city in the field city.

And this is where where it doesn't work. I've tried to create an object with label / value :

```
autoCompleteData.push({cp: values[1]+'', city: values[2] + ''})
```

If I do a `console.log()`, I can see my object but I have difficulty to use it in order to use it in response needed by jquery ui autocomplete. I've seen some examples based on json response but I don't know how to adapt this to my needs. I've also tried to convert my object to json but doesn't work.

Could your explain me how to do this ?

Here is my working code

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "path-to-file/ZipCodes.txt?id=1",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (data) {
                    var autoCompleteData = data.split('\n');
                    var lines = data.split(/\r\n|\n/);

                    //Set up the data arrays
                    var autoCompleteData = Array();
                    for (var j = 0; j < lines.length; j++) {
                        var values = lines[j].split(';'); // Split up the comma seperated values
                        //postcodes.push(values[1], values[2]);
                        autoCompleteData.push(values[1] + '');
                        //autoCompleteData.push({cp: values[1], city: values[2] + ''});
//console.log(autoCompleteData[0][1]);
                $("#edit-code-postal").autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        var results =     $.ui.autocomplete.filter(autoCompleteData, request.term);
                        response(results.slice(0, 10)); // Display the first 10 results
                    },
                    // We fill the city field
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        // here I need help to use my object
                    }

                });
            }
        });
```

And a working snippet without Ajax since I can't load my file on SO. I juste use an array instead :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [
    "FR;24001;Périgueux",
    "FR;24002;Périgueux",
    "FR;24100;Saint-Laurent-des-Vignes",
    "FR;24100;Lembras",
    "FR;24100;Bergerac"
  ];
  //var autoCompleteData = data.split('\n');
  var lines = data;

  //Set up the data arrays
  var data1 = [];
  var data2 = [];
  var data3 = [];
  var autoCompleteData = Array();

  //var headings = lines[0].split(';'); // Splice up the first row to get the headings

  for (var j = 0; j < lines.length; j++) {
    var values = lines[j].split(';'); // Split up the comma seperated values

    //postcodes.push(values[1], values[2]);
    autoCompleteData.push(values[1] + '');
    //autoCompleteData.push({cp: values[1], city: values[2] + ''});

  }

  //console.log(autoCompleteData[0][1]);
  $("#edit-code-postal").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(autoCompleteData, request.term);
      response(results.slice(0, 10)); // Display the first 10 results
    },
    // On remplit aussi la ville
    select: function(event, ui) {
      $('#edit-ville').val(ui.item.city);
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Postal code (try "24...": </label>
    <input id="edit-code-postal">
    <label for="tags">City: </label>
    <input id="edit-ville">
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

```
                    }
                    //console.log(autoCompleteData[0][1]);
                    $("#edit-code-postal").autocomplete({
                        source: function (request, response) {
                            var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(autoCompleteData, request.term);
                            response(results.slice(0, 10)); // Display the first 10 results
                        },
                        // On remplit aussi la ville
                        select: function (event, ui) {
                            $('#edit-ville').val(ui.item.city);
                        }

                    });
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push two values in `autoCompleteData` one will be `label` which we will be using in searching input field values  and other any variable i.e : in below code i have use `data: values[2]` then we get this value and apply to your textbox using `$('#edit-ville').val(ui.item.data);`

**Demo code** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [
    "FR;24001;Périgueux",
    "FR;24002;Périgueux",
    "FR;24100;Saint-Laurent-des-Vignes",
    "FR;24100;Lembras",
    "FR;24100;Bergerac"
  ];
  //var autoCompleteData = data.split('\n');
  var lines = data;

  //Set up the data arrays
  var autoCompleteData = Array();

  for (var j = 0; j < lines.length; j++) {
    var values = lines[j].split(';'); // Split up the comma seperated values
    autoCompleteData.push({
      label: values[1],
      data: values[2] 
    });

  }

  //console.log(autoCompleteData[0][1]);
  $("#edit-code-postal").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(autoCompleteData, request.term);
      response(results.slice(0, 10)); // Display the first 10 results
    },
    // On remplit aussi la ville
    select: function(event, ui) {
      $('#edit-ville').val(ui.item.data);//setting value in textfield
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Postal code (try "24...": </label>
    <input id="edit-code-postal">
    <label for="tags">City: </label>
    <input id="edit-ville">
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Great. I am mostly a PHP developper and I don't exactly understand how `ui.item.data` works in `$('#edit-ville').val(ui.item.data);` Could you explain ?I think that was the issue for me.

Comment: autocomplete will take `label` and `value` to show result when you search , so if you don't provide this it will not display anything in your search textbox .In your current code you where using `cp: values[1] ` which was not recognize by autocomplete. that's the reason it was not working .Also read [this](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)